# Maybe I've found a bug of concurrenthashmap

Tags: java-8, concurrenthashmap

When I want to implement a^b efficiently, I used concurrent hashmap to store calculated value, and the code is

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,Long> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap();

public long pow(long a, long b){
    System.out.printf("%d ^ %d%n",a,b);
    if(b == 1L){
        return a;
    }
    if( b == 2L){
        return a*a;
    }
    long l = b/2;
    long r = b - l;

    return cache.computeIfAbsent(a+","+l,k->pow(a,l)) * cache.computeIfAbsent(a+","+r,k->pow(a,r));
}
```

then I call this method

```
pow(2, 30);
```

but after outputting

```
2 ^ 30
2 ^ 15
2 ^ 7
```

it is blocked , by using `jstack -l pid` I got below info

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f910e801800 nid=0x1703 runnable [0x0000700000217000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1718)
    at interview.Pow.pow(Pow.java:28)
    at interview.Pow.lambda$pow$0(Pow.java:28)
    at interview.Pow$$Lambda$1/1807837413.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    - locked <0x000000076b72d930> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ReservationNode)
    at interview.Pow.pow(Pow.java:28)
    at interview.Pow.lambda$pow$0(Pow.java:28)
    at interview.Pow$$Lambda$1/1807837413.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    - locked <0x000000076b72d060> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ReservationNode)
    at interview.Pow.pow(Pow.java:28)
    at interview.Pow.testPow(Pow.java:32)
```

At first I doubt maybe deadlock happened, then after tracing source code of `ConcurrentHashmap`, I know actually it is dead loop.
When key is `2,3`, it has the same index `9` of key `2,15`, but `fh`(fh = f.hash) is `-3`, cannot meet

```
if (fh >= 0) {...}
```

So in this case, it cannot break the loop

```
for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {...}
```

and loop infinitely.

Is it a bug or designed this so deliberately?

Comment: You invoke `pow` recursively while running `computeIfAbsent` on your map. As a consequence, you have two attempts to write into the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As C-Otto already commented, you invoke a second `computeIfAbsent()`from within the first `computeIfabsent()` method call. [The documentation for this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) clearly states:

> Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and **must not attempt to update any other mappings of this map.**

So this is no bug in the `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation but in your code.

Comment: Yeah, ConcurrentHashMap is just designed for concurrent use not recursively use, so if know there is no concurrent operation it should be changed to use normal HashMap. But maybe in some rare scenarios there are concurrent operation and recursive operation at the same time. So in this case what map I should use? Collections.synchronizedMap()?